# Can i insert a value using "where"

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

can i use

insert into (Table)
              values(xyz)
              where (xzy)

I am inserting values based of a checkbox selection

```
begin
  for idx in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count
  loop
    if apex_application.g_f01(idx) is not null then
       insert into CONSOLIDATE
         (filenumber, 
          INCOMINGDATE,
          filename
         )
         values
         (apex_application.g_f01(idx),
          apex_application.g_f03(idx),
          apex_application.g_f04(idx)


         );
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

which works great ..but now i want to use where Temporary='yes' in that statement..

I know u can use insert into (select x,y,z) where (xyz)
but i want the specific values from the check box..

Comment: What does `Temporary` mean here? Is that another checkbox/formfield value? If so, you would want to check that in the `if` statement above the insert and either execute or not execute the insert based on that value, right?

Comment: temporary is  a field

Comment: It looks like you have the [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't use `WHERE`, but you can use `CASE`, e.g.

```
values
     (case when apex_application.g_f01(idx) in ('A', 'B', 'C') then apex_application.g_f01(idx)
           else null
      end,
      apex_application.g_f01(idx),
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, just select your check box values from dual and apply where condition as necessary

```
begin
  for idx in 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count
  loop
    if apex_application.g_f01(idx) is not null then
       insert into CONSOLIDATE
         (filenumber, 
          INCOMINGDATE,
          filename
         )
         SELECT
          apex_application.g_f01(idx),
          apex_application.g_f03(idx),
          apex_application.g_f04(idx)
         FROM DUAL
         WHERE apex_application.g_f01(idx) = 'XYZ'  ;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```